# how to make a icon get out from container on flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi guys i'm try to make this on flutter: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78He6.png)

i'm try with that code, but work

````
    Container(
      child: Positioned(top:0, left:0)
    )```
````

Answer (score 0):

as an option you can use `Stack` as container for card widget + image

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 80,
                ),
              ),
              FractionalTranslation(
                translation: Offset(0, -0.5),
                child: Icon(Icons.android, size: 48),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]